# how can i call javascript function when clicking on image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I call a js function so it work on click image?

```
$("#closeButton").click(function () {
   $("#sheet").css("display", "none");
});
```

image code?

```
<img src="images/divclose.png" alt="*"  onclick="function()"/>
```

Comment: give the image `id="closeButton"`.

Comment: +1 because sample code is given. Even though we can see the author does not understand very much from topic he provided his sample code and asks an easy question. So plz stop downvoting (imho).

Comment: You could spare time if you enter your question-title directly into google or into stackoverflows search box :)

Comment: I recommend to read http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ and http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add an ID (remove your onclick thingy):

   ```
   <img src="images/divclose.png" alt="*" id="closeButton" />
   ```
2. Write this (note that you don't need the outer function anymore if you already have it);

   ```
   $(function () {
     $("#closeButton").click(function () {
       $("#sheet").css("display", "none");
     });
   });
   ```
3. Now, go reading a beginner tutorial, a book or whatever. Learn the basics ;)

Comment: Why need an extra $(function().. block? Wouldn't the selector part be enough? I would also assume when using an extra block putting it into the .ready() block ?

Comment: @Stefan The OP didn't post his complete code, so I thought I'd better post a complete sample, before the OP claims that it doesn't work ;) I added a hint, now.

Answer (score 1):

You try to access the image using an id in your code, but you don't have any id on the image element. Just add that, and it will work (provided that you have your code inside the `ready` or `load` event, so that the element exists when it runs):

```
<img src="images/divclose.png" alt="*" id="closeButton"/>
```

Don't have any `onclick` attribute on the element if you want to bind the event using jQuery. The event model is somewhat different for jQuery, and may conflict with plain DOM events.

Comment: Just an addition: one can also place the JS code after the *<img>* element in the HTML.

Comment: @ComFreek but why should one? separating js code from html code makes readability, maintanability and usability better.

Comment: @Stefan Of course, but it's good to know that piece of information imho.

Answer (score 0):

tag must have the "id" and you can use the same method you described

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use jquery so you should check jquery documentation.

What you did is declaring an "oldschool" pure javascript way to call `"function()"` on the click.

Therefor you need to declare the function "function" in the javascript itself the old fashioned way.

Using jquery and your code all you need is to assign your id to your image.

```
<img src ="foo.png" id="closeButton"/>
```

and it should work.